# Angular Project SCSS error cannot find angular material import

Tags: javascript, mongodb, scss-mixins, visual-studio-code-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOaO4.png)I have searched all over Stack Overflow and seen similar errors, some suggested changing `@import "-@angular/material/themeing`" to `@use` rather but still no luck, some said there was an error in it loading to the `dist` folder but I was unsuccessful at fixing that. It gives error when trying to open it on web browser.

Trying to resolve this and get all files linked to display nice market website with linked db and custom themes.

Comment: Please post your traceback as text directly in the question, not as a link to an image.